# Postgres (or sql) select row with largest date without grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, typeorm

I have a Posgres typeorm entity with the following columns

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column({ type: 'timestamp with time zone', name: '_createdAt', default: () => 'LOCALTIMESTAMP' })
_createdAt: string
```

I would like to create a query that gets me the row with the latest _createdAt, so i wrote the following query:

```
const maxQb = await MyEntity
    .createQueryBuilder("myEntity")
    .select('Max("_createdAt")', 'max_date')
    .addSelect("id", "id")
    .getRawOne();
```

But this gives me the following error:
"column "myEntity.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause"
The thing is, is don't want to group by id, I want the latest row in the entire database.

So I have tried to write something like this:

```
const maxQb = await myEntity
    .createQueryBuilder("myEntity")
    .select('Max("_createdAt")', 'max_date')
    .getRawOne();

if(!maxQb)
    return null;

return myEntity
    .createQueryBuilder("myEntity")
    .where("myEntity._createdAt >= :max_date", {max_date: maxQb.max_date})
    .select('id', 'id')
    .getOne();
```

This seems to work fine in my localhost, but when I move to a remote server there is a small issue with the maxdate that is being selected which is a milliseconds later then the actual db value, i guess this is some problem with timestamp being saved as a string or something like that.

What would be the best way to achieve what im looking for here?

Thanks in advance,
Gabi.

Comment: Instead of selecting max(_createdAt), do `ORDER BY "_createdAt" DESC LIMIT 1`. I'm not familiar with typeorm so can't spreak to how to how to get it to generate that SQL.

Comment: And yet another way without max() is: `select * from tbl t where not exists(select * from tbl x where x.zdate > t.zdate)`

Comment: Step 1: Fix this error "*some problem with timestamp being saved as a string*".  Until that is corrected  you stand to have all kinds of problems with that column.